# Run function has some invalid argument type (image)- Powerapp

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

i need to send a uploaded image to power automate flow in power app i am getting an error  Run function has some invalid argument type (image)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way of passing image file to Power automate flow as input from Power Apps is depend on which trigger you are using in your flow - PowerApps or PowerApps (V2).

If you are using `PowerApps` trigger:

You have to pass the image file in binary data format using `JSON()` function and then convert it again in your Power Automate flow.

Example:

```
FlowName.Run(JSON(UploadedImage1.Image,JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData));
```

**Detailed article**: [Upload Photos from Power Apps to Sharepoint using Power Automate](https://medium.com/@mateen462/upload-photos-from-power-apps-to-sharepoint-using-power-automate-5aacae5d265d)

If you are using `PowerApps (V2)` trigger:

You have to pass the image file in object format with file name and content.

For example:

```
FlowName.Run(
    {
        contentBytes: UploadedImage1.Image,
        name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss")
    }
);
```

**Detailed article**: [Power Apps Add Picture Control And Save To SharePoint Library](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-add-picture-control-and-save-to-sharepoint-library/)

---

There is a Microsoft Power Automate template available as well which you can try: [Upload a photo to SharePoint from Power Apps](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/templates/details/fe971b57c1994482b565ccfce936900d/upload-a-photo-to-sharepoint-from-power-apps?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)